# Eeeek! what is happening to my profile image in chat

Tags: bug, chat, profile-picture

I posted my meta  profile link in chat and my image got defected

this is how its looks in my profile as you can see

> [image]

[and in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/10533438#10533438)

> [image]

I want  that butterfly back  :)

Comment: Maybe it flew away.

Comment: Why are you posting this twice?

Comment: @balpha its different .. first one about the uses [avatar](http://i.stack.imgur.com/whOYX.png) and this one occur when posing profile link in chat

Comment: That doesn't make it different, just because it's a different user or a different place the avatar is displayed.

Comment: @balpha its at the different place ... so i thought its different .. sorry